# Target specific instance of CSS class

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way for me to target the third div is this list and apply a new CSS class to it?

With CSS, JS or jQuery if possible. (or anything else anyone can think of)

```
<div class="item"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
```

Comment: assign id and refer the div

Comment: “With JS or jQuery if possible” is a strange requirement. Pure CSS solutions are inferior, then?

Comment: You should require a pure-css approach, only if it's cross-browser, if it's not then a javascript one if possible, or using any library that you are / will use in that project

Comment: Something I can think of to solve this with is with a CSS-Book. But it requires reading. Also searching could help. But it requires searching.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [nth-child doesn't respond to class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3203313/367456) and most likely a lot of other ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$("div.item:eq(2)").addClass("test");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mETKW/)

Comment: jQuery is not a solution for everything, he is asking for CSS either JS

Comment: No no, jQuery is OK too. I'll try this now...

Comment: To target the `<p>` instead: `$("div.item:eq(2) p").addClass("test");`

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a CSS class. CSS has selectors. One type of selector is the class selector. HTML has classes.

You can combine any number of selectors you like. It sounds like you want the [nth-child psuedo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

```
.item:nth-child(3) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as “CSS class”, still less instances thereof. What you want is to target the third one among `div` elements that belong to a certain class (which is assigned to it in HTML markup).

The answer is that this depends on the surrounding context. There is no way to target the desired element without knowing how this sequence of `div` elements is nested within other elements and what elements (especially `div` elements may appear before it).

If we assume, for example, that these elements constitute the content of an element like `<div class=foo>...</div>`, then it’s simple:

```
.foo > :nth-child(3) { /* CSS declarations here */ }
```

The `:nth-child()` pseudo-class isn’t supported by some old versions of IE, though.

Answer (score 4):

**Pure JavaScript solution**

You can use `getElementsByClassName`:

```
// Gets the third element with the class "item"
element = document.getElementsByClassName("item")[2];
// Assigns a new class to it
element.setAttribute("class", "newclass");
```

Comment: Good answer. When the pure JS solution is this simple, why use jQuery? :)

Comment: @IsisCode Because people tend to think that jQuery is the solution to everything. They rather include a giant library to to achieve simple things than have an additional line of code here and there. I know, it's sad...

Answer (score 3):

If you want a CSS solution than you can do it like

```
div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
   /* Target 3rd div */
}
```

This won't add a class but will target 3rd `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tGwh/)

---

I don't know what downvotes are for, but also make sure you bind these elements inside a wrapper element say `div` having class for example `wrapper` so the selector will be

```
div.wrapper > div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
   /* Styles here */
}
```

Comment: LOL -1 for my answer? Reason please

Comment: @Daft I don't care if I get downvotes, but I want the reason for downvoting too as I suggested this solution first and rest all of them suggested the same thing, but don't know whats wrong with my answer, anyways you welcome :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess that it's because that approach wouldn't work on IE versions lower than 9, which would make a good poin...

Comment: @aleation http://selectivizr.com/ :) and he tagged this as css and js, so I provided an alternative, it's upto op to choose which one he wants to go for, may be this will be helpful to other users

Comment: But some people (like me XD) don't like to be loading libraries for this kind of stuff, when you can use standard and crossbrowser approaches, That's why I gave him a javascript approach instead of a jQuery one

Comment: @aleation **I provided an alternative**

Comment: is the nth-of-type(x) which wouldn't work on older browsers, again, I don't downvote normally, and didn't on your answer xD

Comment: @aleation shhh, cool down, I didn't said you down voted, the thing is we have different approaches, so posting correct answer but a different approach is not a WRONG answer, so I told you that this is an alternative, anyone can go for this whoever likes to.. there is nothing bad in doing so, and if 1 library can save your from writing jquery for each such thing, I would prefer that, whoever downvotes should downvote on wrong answers, not on correct ones, p.s even I hardly down vote :) and you can see quentins answer, we have the same thing..do you see the difference?

Comment: I know what you mean, it's just that the non-crossbrowser approaches are not very welcome normally, also, if he's willing to use jQuery, I guess it's better to use jQuery rather than adding another library when jQuery can do that in a cross-browser way

Answer (score 3):

With plain JS:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
myItem = items[2]; // as the first element is 0, third element is position 2 in the array;
myItem.setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
```

a shorter way would be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item')[2].setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
```

---

You have to be careful with this method and the others, because if there are other things on page with the class "item" it will count as well, the best you can do is to wrap all those divs inside a parent div, give that parent div an ID or something, and target the parent div instead.

Comment: Nice one-liner, also, good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for find class 'item' with [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) ask for the 3 one and add class:

```
$('.item:nth-of-type(3)').addClass('new-class');
```

Answer (score 1):

For marku up like this-

```
 <div id="div1" class="someclass">
        <img ... id="image1" name="image1" />
    </div>
```

You can do this in javascript-

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
```

And can use addClass method in jQuery.