# CSS :last-child unexpected behaviour

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I am trying to use the last-child operator to hide the last div which applies a border. My issue is that the las div still has the border on the bottom

Below is the HTML for my Test

```
<div class="car-search">
    <!--other divs removed for example-->
    <div class="border-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="car-search">
    <!--other divs removed for example-->
    <div class="border-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.car-search .border-bottom{
    border-bottom: 1px solid $lighterGrey;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 770px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.car-search:last-child .border-bottom{
    display: none;
}
```

I have no idea why the border is being displayed on the last `.car-search`

**Current Output:**

```css
.car-search .border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.car-search:last-child .border-bottom {
  display: none;
}
```

---

**Attempts**

I have also tried using the `!important` tag with no success

I have tried `:last-of-type` with no success

Comment: use `!important` to get rid of that border

Comment: Tried without success

Comment: @Amitsingh No! Don't use `!important` at all. There should be no requirement to use `!important` here anyway, since there is no definition for `display` on the preceding selector.

Comment: @Kieranmv95: Do you have any elements after the last `.car-search`? If you do then the `.car-search` is not the `:last-child` of its parent and hence the selector won't work. Have a look at this thread for details on how `:last-child` works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#18995451.

Comment: @Kieranmv95: Stack snippet adds an extra children (`<script>`) after the element within the body and so don't go by its output. Copy the same code into a fiddle and you will note that the second border doesn't appear.

Comment: @Harry its appearing in my live project thoguh

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/ggrxLdbo/

Comment: @Kieranmv95 Post your full code please.

Comment: @Kieranmv95: As I said in my earlier comment, you might be having some other children tag after the last `.car-search` within the `body` or whichever is the parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203313/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class-selector

Comment: @cimmanon its not a dupe because last-of-type also doesnt work for me :/

Comment: The answers specifically specifies what you're trying to do doesn't work.  Just because the alternative doesn't work does not make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @Kieranmv95: In case you didn't understand my previous comments, have a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/sabsdc6m/. The `.car-search` is not the `:last-child` here because the last child is the `div` without any class. `last-of-type` also won't work here because the last `div` is the last of its type and hence the border would remain. I may sound like a broken record but please look at all the three threads linked here to see how exactly `:last-child` and `last-of-type` work. Judging by comments, I do think you have an extra `div` element after the last `.car-search`.

Comment: can you do something like this instead of adding another `div` for `border` http://jsfiddle.net/sabsdc6m/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above there is no :last-of-class selector for now so the only way to do it is javascript. With jQuery you can run the following code:

```
jQuery('div.car-search:last .border-bottom').css({display:'none'});
```

Moreover with scss you can write

```
.car-search {
    .border-bottom {
        border-bottom: 1px solid $lighterGrey;
        padding-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        width: calc(100% - 30px);
        margin-left: 15px;    
    }

    &:last-of-type {
        .border-bottom {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is a bit less of scss lines.

In compiled CSS:

```
.car-search .border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $lighterGrey;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;    
}

.car-search:last-of-type .border-bottom {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there are other `<div>` children after the last `.car-search`.

Comment: You might want to use/add the compiled CSS in this answer. Not everyone uses or understands SCSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p7xbmryr/1/

Comment: I really like this solution but it isn't working for me, thanks for showing me you can add things to the end though. I'm new to scss

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no `last-of-class` selector inside of CSS. You'll either need to remove the `.border-bottom` element from your last `.car-search` element, or fall back to Javascript / jQuery to remove the element from the DOM.

For example, you could run the following jQuery code to remove the last `.car-search` element's `.border-bottom`:

```
$('.car-search').last().children('.border-bottom').remove();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7xbmryr/)

Alternatively, if you wish to use pure CSS for this, you could wrap your `.car-search` elements inside of a container `<div>` and use the [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-of-type) selector.

For example, your new structure might look like:

```
<div class="car-search-wrapper">    
    <div class="car-search">
        <!--other divs removed for example-->
        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="car-search">
        <!--other divs removed for example-->
        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you may use:

```
.car-search:last-of-type .border-bottom {
    display: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7xbmryr/2/)

Comment: Even that might not work if there is another element of type `div` after the `.car-search`.

Comment: Good point, updating.

Comment: Another option (instead of falling back to JS) is to wrap all the `.car-search` inside an wrapper element (like a `div`)