# Alternate style with nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm struggling with my styles.

I'd like to alternate the blue and green *bubbles* (*blue > green > blue > green* ...). Only the `.bubble` element should have a *background-color* that alternates. The `.input` should remain as is.

Here is my simplified code.

```css
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container .bubble:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #4a94ed;
    border-color: #4a64ed;
}


.container .bubble:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #4df200;
    border-color: #00f23d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 1</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 2</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 3</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 4</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 5</div>
</div>
```

My issue seems to come from the `.input` elements that count as an `nth-child` since **only the `even` part triggers**.

Unfortunately, I can't change the HTML structure nor classes.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am sure this same question has been asked multiple times. You shouldn't use `odd` and `even` for your case. Instead use `nth-child(4n)` for even and `nth-child(4n+2)` for odd. Each `.bubble` item is the even child of its parent (that is, the 2nd child, the 4th child and so on..).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-child doesn't respond to class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203313/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class-selector)

Comment: @Harry you were right. Do you wanna post it as an anwser?

Comment: @pistou: I think I've myself posted atleast 2-3 answers on very similar lines and anymore would look like rep-hunting, so I will leave it there (too lazy to search for the primary question :D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your odd and even styles to:

```
.container .bubble:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #4a94ed;
    border-color: #4a64ed;
}

.container .bubble:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #4df200;
    border-color: #00f23d;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/VjYYXd

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. Only the `.bubble` elements should have a `background-color`, that alternates.

Comment: Oh no, that's my misunderstanding! 

I've tweaked the code pen to use the nth-child(2/4n) selector like @Harry suggested. Hopefully that should be you up and running!

Answer (score 3):

```
    .bubble:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: #4a94ed;
    border-color: #4a64ed;
}

 .bubble:nth-child(4n+4) {
    background-color: #4df200;
    border-color: #00f23d;
}
```

try this at my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ua51sum/7/

Answer (score 2):

This Will Work....

```
.bubble:nth-child(2n) {background-color: #4a94ed;
border-color: #4a64ed;}
.bubble:nth-child(4n){background-color: #4a94ed;
border-color: #4a64ed;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your nth child selectors as following `:nth-child(4n+2)` or `:nth-child(4n)`.

```css
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container .bubble:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #4a94ed;
    border-color: #4a64ed;
}


.container .bubble:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #4df200;
    border-color: #00f23d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 1</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 2</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 3</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 4</div>
    <div class="input">input</div>
    <div class="bubble">bubble 5</div>
</div>
```