# nth-child(2n) CSS after hidden tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table looks like this (below) after using css nth-child(2n).

```
tr:nth-child(2n) {background-color: #f0f3f5;}
```

[image]

After doing some hidden on the vID,ID,MO_Sub tr

```
<tr style="display:none">
```

The table now looks like this below, with backgroung on "MO" and "MODEL".

[image]

I have done somthing like (below) and it doesn't seem to work.

```
tr:not(.isotope-hidden):nth-child(2n)
```

Anyone got any idea applying css after the hidden tr?
Thanks for any helps! =)

EDIT: add snippet

```css
tr:not([style*="display:none"]):nth-child(2n){
    background-color: #f0f3f5;
}

tr:hover{

    background-color: cadetblue;

}
```

```html
 <table id="form_tb">
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>vvID :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="vvID" placeholder="vvID" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>vID :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="vID" placeholder="vID" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>vID_sub :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="vID_sub" placeholder="vID_sub" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>ST :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Station" placeholder="Station" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>SortID :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="SortID" placeholder="SortID" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>MO :</label></td>
                        <td data-key='MO'><input id=MO type="text" name="MO" placeholder="MO" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>MO_Sub :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="MO_Sub" placeholder="MO_Sub" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>PART :</label></td>
                        <td data-key='text'><input type="text" name="Part_number" placeholder="PART" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>MODEL :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Model" placeholder="MODEL" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><label>Class :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Product_Class" placeholder="Class" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Side :</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Side" placeholder="Side" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </table>
```

Result for the snippet should look like this.(below)

[image]

Comment: Your CSS selector `tr:not(.isotope-hidden):nth-child(2n)` should work just fine. Try using the `.isotope-hidden` class to hide your the table row instead of an inline `display: none`.

Comment: Code snippets instead of images would be better, that way we can fiddle around to get it working without having to create everything ourselves

Comment: inline css takes precedence over classes. But using `!important` should override inline if it's not already using it

Comment: added the code snippets

Comment: Is expected result for only `<tr>` having `<td>` with text set to `"PART"` to have `background` property applied?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, something like that.  For only `<tr>` having `<td>` which it's 2n to have background.

Answer (score 3):

The n-th child selector only selects children that are the nth child of the parent. 
In your case, it selects table.children[n] such that n is even. Counterintuitively, it doesn't match the even values of the filtered results.

To fix the :hover problem, you could add :not(:hover) to the first css selector, but this doesn't fix everything.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203313/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class-selector) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057925/select-odd-even-child-excluding-the-hidden-child) question are both questions that deal with the same issue.

Might be better to use JavaScript, in this case.

Comment: doesn't seem to work tho :S
show up as same as before